# swift UIButton.selected won't work

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm trying to keep a button selected while its audio is being played. the problem is the button won't change unless I change it in a loop (while(audioPlayer.playing){button.selcted=true}). In this case I can't use the app until audio has finished(for obvious reasons)

hopefully someone can help me

```
func addButton(number: String, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat){

    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

    button.setTitle(number, forState: .Normal)

    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 68, 212)

    if let image  = UIImage(named: number) {
        button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    }

    button.addTarget(self, action: "play:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}

@IBAction func play(sender: UIButton) {
    button=sender

    button.selected = true

    let audioFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sender.currentTitle, ofType: "WAV")

    if audioFilePath != nil {

        let audioFileUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(audioFilePath!)

        do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileUrl, fileTypeHint: nil)} catch _ { return }
        audioPlayer?.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.play()

    } else {
        print("audio file is not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: are you saying you are losing the selected state when it is not in a loop?  I do not see any distinction between a selected button and a regular button,  so how do you know the state is not changing?  Are you looking to not make it user accessible?  You would use `userInteractionEnabled` for that

Comment: the color won't change as it does in the loop (it dosen't gray out)

Comment: that is not the selected state,  I believe that is the highlighted state constantly getting updated,  try setting that to true

Comment: but I like to keep it grayed out and i cannot change the focused state as it is get only. do you know a way?

Comment: it was highlighted state, not focus,  I got it wrong and changed my comment

Comment: this won't work either. I set button.highlighted = true; no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote up a test app to see what you are actually trying to do here,  set `sender.enabled = false` is what you are looking for.  (The button as an animation that goes to the faded out gray that is set by not enabled,  then goes back to the original color of enabled,  setting it to false prevents the second part from happening)

Edit:  In the end, the results that were desired was an accessible button with the gray text,  so we changed the text highlight state to a gray using `sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(),forState:.Highlighted)` and the user will set the highlighted variable to true in the Play function.

Comment: You are right this changes the color but it fades out and does't gray out and i cannot touch the button again to restart the audio and that is necessary. I just don't know why highlighted or selected won't work without an extra forState image

Comment: if you want that gray state,  you need to change it,  it will not give it to you by default,  You are given the illusion of solid gray when it is constantly flashing back and forth.  The selected state does inverse color by default,  I don't think highlight does anything by default

Comment: is it possible to change the alpha of the button image that might do the trick as well

Comment: sure, you can change anything,  if you want the button accessible at all times,  just change the highlighted state to whatever you want `sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(),forState:.Highlighted)`